# PHP nested problems while querying

Tags: php, loops, nested

I am working on a project. I need to query a DB and write the result to a csv file. The result is going to be over 15,000 entries, (thats what the user wants). I am breaking up the results using the LIMIT because if I don't the DB will time out. I divide the query in what I call total_pages. Here is my code.

The big for loop, loops 19 times. The problems is that the code will go through the nested loop one time ( only 500 entries) then It does not go back in. I tried using null on the $results but no luck.  Please help.

```
// using this for my LIMIT
$start_from = 0; 

$sql = "select * from someplace where gender = '".$gender."'";

$rs_result = mysql_query($sql);

$total_records =  mysql_num_rows($rs_result);

$total_pages = ceil($total_records / 500);

// open a file

//write x in file

file = fopen("./DataFile/gdownload.csv","w");

//write header to the file

$x = "Last Name,First Name,Primary_Name, ........ etc...... \n";

fwrite($file, $x);

for($count = 0; $count <= $total_pages; $count++)
{


    $query = "SELECT * 
             FROM ptable
            JOIN person_name ON ptable.Primary_Name = person_name.Primary_Name
            WHERE gender = '$gender'
            ORDER BY person_name.Lname ASC
            LIMIT ".$start_from.", 500";

    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

    $num_row = mysql_num_rows($result);

    //print tables in rows

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
             $x="";
        $x=$x.$row['Lname'].",";
        $x=$x.$row['Fname'].",";
        $x=$x.$row['Primary_Name'].",";
        $x=$x.$row['asdf#'].",";
        $x=$x.$row['qwer'].",";
        $x=$x.$row['hjkl'].",";
        $x=$x.$row['bnm,'].",";
        $x=$x.$row['yui'].",";
        $x=$x.$row['aaa'].",";
        ..... 
                fwrite($file, $x);
        }// end nested while

        $start_from+=500;
   }// end for loop
   fclose($file);
```

Comment: What do you mean "does not go back in"? I see one for-loop that would do `ceil($total_records / 500) + 1` runs. Where's that 19?

Comment: When I just this search the total_pages is a count, so that I would now how many times to go through the for loop. When I last tried it, it was 19 total_pages.

Comment: ah, check, brainfail @ `ceil` and `/` on my part, don't mind me :)

Answer (score 0):

It could be a problem with your LIMIT condition. What you have seems OK to me but the fact that the rows are only being written on the first pass through makes me think $result is empty after the first pass.

Try changing

`LIMIT ".$start_from.", 500";`

to

```
LIMIT 500 OFFSET ".$start_from;
```

Also make sure the query actually returns more than 500 results.

On a different note, it's odd that the request would timeout on just 15,000 records.

Comment: Thanks, but no Luck. The 1st time through it gets 500 results, but on the 2nd - n times around it gets 0 results. I used the mysql_num_rows and its 0 on all loops except the 1st one.

Comment: The reason its timeout on the 15,000 records is b/e the site is hosted on godaddy, and I exceed the maximum allowed query.

Comment: another shot in the dark, try adding mysql_free_result($result); just before the end of the for loop

Comment: I tried that to, and it did not work. I tried to null all the query variables and the results, with no luck